# Where can I find data of a UV blocking glass absorption filter absorbing the visible light and re-emitting the energy as a photon of NIR?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, energy-conservation, photon-emission

If I understand correctly, a UV Transmitting, visible light absorbing colored glass absorption filter absorbs the visible light energy and re-emits it as near IR.  On Oct 16, 2013 in [How does Infrared Relate to heat?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/80983/how-does-infrared-relate-to-heat?newreg=a9855e2fb3cf449fbc5a885561192c5f)  codeAndStuff said "Photons can be absorbed by a molecule to gain energy" and "when a photon is absorbed, the molecule gains energy, well it can also emit a photon and lower its energy" and "IR light is produced and associated with heat is that you are seeing molecules go from one vibrational quantum state to a lower vibrational quantum state by giving off a photon of appropriate energy (in the IR region).
Where can I find data and graphs that show a UV transmitting visible light blocking colored glass absorption re-emitting the energy as near IR? Here is my conception of what such a graph might look like.[image: graph showing visible light transforming to near IR]

Comment: In many cases there will be quite limited re-emission of anything other than thermal radiation - not all absorbers are molecules with reasonably efficient transitions in the near-IR that could be excited in UV absorption events.

Comment: There are also filters that, e.g., transmit UV and reflect visible light. So the filter does not heat up or sustain damage absorbing the visible light.